# Turning off storage in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

How do I turn remote storage off in Paperclip for use on Heroku? I realize that storing an uploaded file is the whole point of this gem, but I want to turn it off and still use the gem's other features (inspecting the file, etc- just don't need to store). I want to keep all the functionality in place in the model, but just not store the file anywhere.

This is close but it doesn't work on Heroku:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = 'filesystem'
```

This doesn't work unfortunately:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :none
```

Answer (score 0):

From this file

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb

I did not tested this but inside config/initializer/ or production.rb environment you should be able to set

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options = {}
```

or with Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = ""

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Will post a solution when I find it.

Comment: What is the version of paperclip that you are using?

Comment: 5.0.0. I solved the problem by specifying filesystem storage, and having the path be the `tmp` directory (which isn't persisted between deployments on Heroku, but still works for my purposes).